# Do I need permissions on Facebook to share using SocialAuth?

Tags: android, facebook, socialauth

So, I'm developing an android application that allows the user to share to facebook. I'm constantly getting the toast from the library of "Message not postedfacebook" once I use the updateStory function.

Is this because I need to have the permission setup through Facebook to share to a user's feed, or is it something else? I'll provide snippets of my code if necessary, but I don't necessarily think it is necessary because I can authorize to facebook using my key and secret.

Comment: There is no permission required for posting in FB. You should cross check your app Public settings is enable or not in Facebook.

Comment: What API are you calling at Facebook?

Comment: @SimplePlan I went to my app and looked for where to set it to public.  The only thing that had anything to do with public vs private was in the app center permissions for the app itself. Is this setting somewhere else? Sorry for not being able to follow completely. This is my first time setting something up like this.

Comment: @tdonaldson1713 go to `https://developers.facebook.com/apps`-->select your `app`-->then go to `Status & Review` --> enable `Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?` option. It'll take around 1-2 hours to reflect.

Comment: @SimplePlan So, I have done what you said and have waited about 11 hours total between tests to see if I could get it to work, but to no avail. I looked on the forums of SocialAuth and someone else posted about an issue with not being able to post. Do you know of a work around to this, or should I just use facebook's sdk instead?

Comment: @tdonaldson1713 OMG!!! Still not working.. i am done this posting using `facebook SDK`. so i would suggest you go with `facebook SDK`

Comment: @SimplePlan Okay. I will go ahead and switch over to that. I figured this might be the easy route for facebook as it was for twitter, but I guess not. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @tdonaldson1713 yo welcome mate! and if you need any more help without hesitate ask me.